# loop for list element with datetime in r

Tags: r, list, loops, datetime, posixlt

### loop for list element with datetime in r

I have a df with name mistake. I splitted the mistake df by ID. Now I have over 300 different objects in the list.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- split.data.frame(mistake, mistake$ID)
```

Every list object has two different datetime stamps. At first I need the minutes between this two datetime stamps. Then I duplicate the rows of the object by the variable stay (this is the difftime between the sat and end time too). Then I overwrite the test variable with the increment n_mintes.

```
library(lubridate)
start_date <- df[[1]]$datetime
end_date <- df[[1]]$gehtzeit
n_minutes <- interval(start_date,end_date)/minutes(1)
see <- start_date + minutes(0:n_minutes)#the diff time in minutes I need 
df[[1]]$test<- Sys.time()#a new variable 
df[[1]] <- data.frame(df[[1]][rep(seq_len(dim(df[[1]])[1]),df[[1]]$stay+1),1:17, drop= F], row.names=NULL)
df[[1]]$test <- format(start_date + minutes(0:n_minutes), format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

I want to do this with every objcet of the list. And then 'rbind' or 'unsplit' my list. I know I need a loop. But I don' t know how to do this with the list element.
Any help would be create!

Here is a small df example;

```
mistake


Baureihe Verbund      Fahrzeug Code                           Codetext    Subsystem          Kommt.Zeit
71      411 ICE1166 93805411866-7 1A50 Querfederdruck 1 ungleich Sollwert Neigetechnik 29.07.2018 23:00:07
72      411 ICE1166 93805411866-7 1A50 Querfederdruck 1 ungleich Sollwert Neigetechnik 04.08.2018 11:16:41
             Geht.Zeit           Anstehdauer Jahr Monat   KW Tag Wartung.geht            datetime            gehtzeit
71 29.07.2018 23:02:56 00 Std 02 Min 49 Sek  2018     7 KW30  29            0 2018-07-29 23:00:00 2018-07-29 23:02:00
72 04.08.2018 11:19:20 00 Std 02 Min 39 Sek  2018     8 KW31   4            0 2018-08-04 11:16:00 2018-08-04 11:19:00
   bleiben                                           ID
71  2 secs 2018-07-29 23:00:00 2018-07-29 23:02:00 1A50
72  3 secs 2018-08-04 11:16:00 2018-08-04 11:19:00 1A50
```

And here ist the structure:

```
    str(mistake)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  18 variables:
 $ Baureihe    : int  411 411
 $ Verbund     : Factor w/ 1 level "ICE1166": 1 1
 $ Fahrzeug    : Factor w/ 7 levels "93805411066-4",..: 7 7
 $ Code        : Factor w/ 6 levels "1A07","1A0E",..: 3 3
 $ Codetext    : Factor w/ 6 levels "ITD Karte gestört",..: 5 5
 $ Subsystem   : Factor w/ 1 level "Neigetechnik": 1 1
 $ Kommt.Zeit  : Factor w/ 70 levels "02.08.2018 00:07:23",..: 68 6
 $ Geht.Zeit   : Factor w/ 68 levels "01.08.2018 01:30:25",..: 68 8
 $ Anstehdauer : Factor w/ 46 levels "00 Std 00 Min 01 Sek ",..: 12 4
 $ Jahr        : int  2018 2018
 $ Monat       : int  7 8
 $ KW          : Factor w/ 5 levels "KW27","KW28",..: 4 5
 $ Tag         : int  29 4
 $ Wartung.geht: int  0 0
 $ datetime    : POSIXlt, format: "2018-07-29 23:00:00" "2018-08-04 11:16:00"
 $ gehtzeit    : POSIXlt, format: "2018-07-29 23:02:00" "2018-08-04 11:19:00"
 $ bleiben     :Class 'difftime'  atomic [1:2] 2 3
  .. ..- attr(*, "units")= chr "secs"
 $ ID          : chr  "2018-07-29 23:00:00 2018-07-29 23:02:00 1A50" "2018-08-04 11:16:00 2018-08-04 11:19:00 1A50"
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput`

Comment: Where is *see* (i.e., *the diff time in minutes I need*) ever used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider building a generalized user-defined function that receives a data frame as input parameter. Then, call the function with `by`. Like `split`, `by` also subsets a data frame by one or more factor(s) such as *ID* but, unlike `split`, `by` can then pass subsets into a function. To row bind all together, run `do.call` at end.

Below removes the redundant `df$test <- Sys.time()` which is overwritten later and uses *see* object inside `format()` call at end to avoid re-calculation and repetition.

```
calc_datetime <- function(df) {
   # INITIAL CALCS
   start_date <- df$datetime
   end_date <- df$gehtzeit
   n_minutes <- interval(start_date, end_date)/minutes(1)
   see <- start_date + minutes(0:n_minutes) # the diff time in minutes I need 

   # BUILD OUTPUT DF
   df <- data.frame(df[rep(seq_len(dim(df)[1]), df$stay+1), 1:17, drop= F], row.names=NULL)
   df$test <- format(see, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")

   return(df)
}

# BUILD LIST OF SUBSETTED DFs
df_list <- by(mistake, mistake$ID, calc_datetime)

# APPEND ALL RESULT DFs TO SINGLE FINAL DF
final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```

Comment: In summary, I can only say one thing: thank you very much It works perfectly. Exactly what I wanted! Thank you thank you thank you

Answer (score 0):

Along the same lines as Parfait's answer, and using the same user defined function `calc_datetime`, but I would use `map_dfr` from the `purrr` package:

```
df_list <- split(mistake, mistake$ID)
final_df <- map_dfr(df_list, calc_datetime)
```

If you update the question to have data I can use I can give a demonstration that works

Comment: In summary, I can only say one thing:
thank you very much It works perfectly. Exactly what I wanted! Thank you thank you thank you

Comment: Glad it worked! You should accept the answer that worked best for you (probably Parfait's since they did most of the work) and upvote any answer that you found helpful